# Java WebView como usar

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Como eu uso o `webview` quando eu uso:

```
public void site(){
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("http://mySite.com");
}
```

Tenho o erro:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<clinit>(WebEngine.java:315)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:273)
```

Preciso usar dentro de uma `void` pois ela sera chamada em um `actionlistener` de um botão mais pra frente.

Comment: De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html): `WebView objects must be created and accessed solely from the FX thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui reproduzir o problema. O problema pode estar na maneira como esse método `site` está sendo chamado, ou em como o método `main` está sendo montado. Baseado no que você deseja fazer no futuro, fiz um exemplo que chama o webview no onAction do botão:

```
public class WebViewExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Button button = new Button("Load");
        button.setOnAction((event) -> {
            WebView browser = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("http://mySite.com");
            vbox.getChildren().add(browser);
        });

        vbox.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```